# how to create shoe sizes attributein magento with UK, US and EU sizes

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, attribute-set

I have a magento Website , I need to upload the shoes of different sizes . I have created 10 simple products and then connected to a configurable product.
The front end needs to display sizes of EU, US and UK. Check the below link for 
 reference.
https://en-ae.namshi.com/buy-hey-dude-moka-classic-lace-up-slip-ons-for-women-slip-ons-105341.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a completely different store for each country and do not want to show different size options in different stores you you could simply use the different attribute option labels for each store.

This can be setup via the admin or via a script but simply for each option set the UK store label to be the UK size, US store label to be the US size and the EA store label to be EU size. In this way each store will have a different display value but each shoe will be the same.

Comment: yes I understood.. But the thing is we have  for one country that is United Arab Emirates. I want to display all the sizes in one store itself, I want it like the one shown in the reference URL.

Comment: then in that case you will need either some custom coding or a lot of products. To do this via "standard" magento code you could add a custom attribute size_type e.g. UK, US, EA then for each product you would need a product just for each type. Then when building configurable products you need to configure type first then size.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any plugin you can recommend so that I can skip the coding part because this is an urgent requirement. If not I will have to develop it .